# Symfony Routing: Allow only defined parameters

Tags: symfony, routes, silex

```
$controllers->get('/thumb/add/{thumb}/{object}/{objectId}', 'globe.controller:addThumbAction')
            ->bind('thumb.add')
            ->before(function(Request $request) use ($app) {
                if ( !$app['user'] ) {
                    throw new AccessDeniedException('You cannot add a thumb without login');
                }
            });
```

I use Silex with the `contoller collection`. For this route, `thumb` can only be 0 or 1. `object` is `int` and have to be between `1 and 3`. `objectId` should be tested for an int value.

I know, that I can use `->assert('id', '\d+')` for testing if `int`.

Can someone help me, how to test `thumb` and `object` for explained criteria?

Answer (score 2):

The asserts are regular expressions so (I think) you could just use the following.

```
->assert('thumb', '[01]')    // Either 0 or 1
->assert('id', '[1-3]')      // 1, 2 or 3
->assert('objectId', '\d+')   // One or more digits
```